# Linux system calls C code errors when I run make

Tags: c, linux, makefile, virtualbox, system-calls

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/pinfo.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <asm/current.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

#define NSEC 1000000000
#define time_cal(t) \
t->start_time.tv_sec * NSEC + t->start_time.tv_nsec

// Prototype functions
int get_PID(void);
long get_state(void);
long get_nice(void);
unsigned long get_start_time(void);
int get_parent_id(void);
int get_children(void);
int get_youngest_child(void);
int get_younger_silbing(void);
int get_older_sibling(void);
long get_user_time(void);
long get_sys_time(void);
char * get_comm(void);
long get_UID(void);

// Global var used to get the task struct
struct task_struct *get_t;

// Process ID
int get_PID(void){
    return get_t->pid;
}

// Current state of process (-1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped)
long get_state(void){
return get_t->state;
}

// Process nice value range from -20 <> 19 (high prio neg values & lower 
prio pos values)
long get_nice(void){
return (get_t->prio - MAX_RT_PRIO - 20);
}

// Process id of parent
int get_parent_id(void){
return get_t->parent->pid;
}

// Total number of children
int get_children(void){
struct list_head *tmp;
int i = 0;
// Traverse the doubly linked list to get the number of children
list_for_each(tmp, &get_t->children){ ++i; }
// no children then return -1
if(i == 0){ return -1; }
else{ return i; }
}

// PID of the youngest child
int get_youngest_child(void){
// get the list of childrens
struct list_head *tmp = &get_t->children;
int pid;
if(&tmp == NULL){ return -1; }
// use macro to get the task_struck embedded
// Note: list_entry( ptr, type, member)
pid = list_entry(tmp->prev, struct task_struct, children)->pid;
// if list_entry ret is zero or the pid is the same as its self then return 
-1
if(pid == 0 || pid == get_PID()){return -1;}
return pid;
}

// PID of younger sibling
int get_younger_sibling(void){
// get the list of siblings
struct list_head *tmp = &get_t->sibling;
int pid;
if(&tmp == NULL){return -1;}
// use macro to get the task_struck embedded
// Note: list_entry( ptr, type, member)
pid = list_entry(tmp->next, struct task_struct, sibling)->pid;
// if list_entry ret is zero or the pid is the same as its self then return 
-1
if(pid == 0 || pid == get_PID()) {return -1;}
return pid;
}

// PID of older sibling
int get_older_sibling(void){
// get the list of sibling
struct list_head *tmp = &get_t->sibling;
int pid;
if(&tmp == NULL){return -1;}
// use macro to get the task_struck embedded
// Note: list_entry( ptr, type, member)
pid = list_entry(tmp->prev, struct task_struct, sibling)->pid;
// if list_entry ret is zero or the pid is the same as its self then return 
-1
if(pid == 0 || pid == get_PID()) {return -1;}
return pid;
}

// Process start time
unsigned long get_start_time(void){
return time_cal(get_t);
}

// CPU time spent in user mode
long get_user_time(void){
return get_t->utime;
}

// CPU time spent in system mode
long get_sys_time(void){
return get_t->stime;
}

// User id of process owner
long get_UID(void){
return get_t->uid;
}

// Name of program executed
char * get_comm(void){
return get_t->comm;
}

asmlinkage long sys_pinfo(struct pinfo *process){
// if the user didn't provide stack or heap space then return -22
if(&process == NULL){return -22;}

// Fill in the Process Information
get_t = get_current();
process->pid = get_PID();
process->state = get_state();
process->nice = get_nice();
process->parent_pid = get_parent_id();
process->children = get_children();
process->youngest_child_pid = get_youngest_child();
process->younger_sibling_pid = get_younger_sibling();
process->older_sibling_pid = get_older_sibling();
process->start_time = get_start_time();
process->user_time = get_user_time();
process->sys_time = get_sys_time();
process->uid = get_UID();
strcpy(process->comm, get_comm());
return 0;
}
```

And for some reason, when I run make, these are the errors I keep getting:

```
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_nice’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:44:24: error: ‘MAX_RT_PRIO’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
return (get_t->prio - MAX_RT_PRIO - 20);
                    ^
pinfo/pinfo.c:44:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once 
for each function it appears in
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_youngest_child’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:68:10: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘false’ 
for the address of ‘tmp’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
if(&tmp == NULL){ return -1; }
      ^
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_younger_sibling’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:82:10: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘false’ 
for the address of ‘tmp’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
if(&tmp == NULL){return -1;}
      ^
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_older_sibling’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:96:10: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘false’ 
for the address of ‘tmp’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
if(&tmp == NULL){return -1;}
      ^
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_UID’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:122:14: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘uid’
return get_t->uid;
          ^
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘sys_pinfo’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:132:14: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘false’ 
for the address of ‘process’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
if(&process == NULL){return -22;}
          ^
pinfo/pinfo.c:140:9: error: ‘struct pinfo’ has no member named ‘children’
process->children = get_children();
     ^
pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_nice’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:45:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [- 
Werror=return-type]
}
^

pinfo/pinfo.c: In function ‘get_UID’:
pinfo/pinfo.c:123:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [- 
Werror=return-type]
}
^

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [pinfo/pinfo.o] Error 1
make: *** [pinfo] Error 2
```

Does anybody know why I’m getting these errors or how to fix the errors so make will run properly? The code is supposed to be a static system call to incorporate to my custom Linux Kernel. The system call should take one argument and return the process state information for that process, its child processes, child threads and sibling processes. I was told that once I’m done writing my C code, I had to run make then make install but everytime I run make, I get these same errors and I dont know how to fix them. I’m using CentOS VirtualBox. Please help.

Comment: Did you install kernel headers? Like, `yum install kernel-devel`?

Comment: no, I did it prior to making the system call, after creating the system call I have to do all those things again?

Comment: There's quite a few things missing here. `MAX_RT_PRIO` is from `/linux/sched/rt.h` on CentOS 7.3. But it isn't included. Install kernel headers, adjust your source and makefile and try again.

Comment: ok thanks that helps i dont think i installed the headers so ill try that now then try again

Comment: i did yum install kernel-devel and im still getting the same errors? do i have to chage my code at all? as you can see linux/sched is included but still nothing

Comment: The code you've got won't work with this version of Linux kernel. Spend some time reading about kernel programming and then get ready to modify your source code and makefiles. :)